# AmCharts category axis in the 0

Tags: amcharts

I am creating a chart with AmCharts. My chart should look like Stacked bar chart with negative values [example](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/stacked-bar-chart-with-negative-values/), but a little different. I want to make a Y-axis to be in the middle, where x = 0. Moreover, there should be a gap so that axis labels could fit. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0):

The answer came from support. In amCharts you can not place Y axis to the x = 0 point while having negative and positive values simultaniously.